# Program to calculate the average of unknown set of numbers in C

Tags: c

I'm attempting to write a program to calculate the average of the numbers inputted by the user.

The user can input as many numbers as they'd like until they enter 0, which breaks the [while] loop.

The difficulty I have is I don't know how to tell the program to sum an unknown set of numbers.

I've spent hours trying to figure this out (I'm entirely new to programming). I would be grateful for any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int numberEntered;
    int sum = 0;

    printf("Program to calculate the average of a series of numbers\n\n");
    printf("Please enter the first number. Enter 0 to stop: ");

    scanf("%d", &numberEntered);
    while (numberEntered != 0)
    {
        sum = sum + numberEntered;
        printf("Please enter another number. Enter 0 to stop: ");
        scanf("%d", &numberEntered);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, you already computed the sum correctly. What's the next step?

Comment: What is the issue you have? Seems like it does the job, doesn't it?

Comment: This might be a good time to learn about [*rubber duck debugging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Explain the code in detail to your (real or imaginary) rubber duck (friends works equally well). It should hopefully make things clearer for you.

Comment: The next step is to ask the program to calculate the average of the numbers input by the user, but I don't know how to do that. I don't know how to tell the program X number of inputs have been entered.

Comment: First of all, you *do* know how to calculate average? Then you should know that you need to count the number of inputs. Think a little bit on how to do that (hint: it's very similar to what you're already doing with the sum).

Comment: Just add a counter variable that counts the number of inputs (excluding `0`) and then divide by the count after your break the loop (avoiding integer division appropriately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done. Just `count` the number of elements and `divide` the `sum` by `count` to get the `average`. Here `type-casting` is also required, otherwise `average` of 2 and 3 will give you 2 which is incorrect.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
    int numberEntered;
    int sum = 0;

    printf("Program to calculate the average of a series of numbers\n\n");
    printf("Please enter the first number. Enter 0 to stop: ");
    scanf("%d", &numberEntered);

    int count_number = 0;

    while (numberEntered != 0)
    {
    sum = sum + numberEntered;
    count_number++;
    printf("Please enter another number. Enter 0 to stop: ");
    scanf("%d", &numberEntered);
    }
    if(count_number>0)
       {printf("AVG: %f",((float)sum)/count_number);}

    }
```

Comment: You do know `scanf` returns a value that is worth checking?

Comment: @EdHeal You are correct but just trying to make everything as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to also maintain a count of inputs and divide sum by that number in the end after breaking the while loop.

Comment: That's what I don't know how to do.

Comment: ```int`` count = 0; … count++;`, @hailnolly?